# how POI delete namespace of xml in Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I found that POI has this behavior: When the child tag in xml of a Excel file has the same namespace as the parent tag, the namespace of the child tag will be removed. Why is that?

Here are the details：
I have a excel file, I use a decompression software unzip it away, and then opened the file /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml which has the following contents:

the key point of it should be the first and the last part：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on039.png)

then I use POI deal with this Excel, and wrote it out as a another Excel, but the new Excel file delete the namespace of ext tag, you can see it in follwoing picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pepyn.png)

I don't want POI delete the namespace of ext tag. Because spread.js can not work normally for some functions when this happed. I hope anybody can do help

I hope figure out why that is?

Comment: Why are you bothering? The second namespace declaration is superfluous and can be omitted.

Comment: POI writes the Excel file from scratch, it doesn't know nor care that you had this unneeded extra declaration in the original XML. If spread.js can't handle that, then that sounds like a bug in spread.js not conforming to XML specifications.

Comment: I am a little upset because the back end use POI dealing Excel while the front end use spread.js dealing Excel, front end can not work mormally when POI delete the namespace in ext tag of sheet1.xml in Excel , and my customer need me to fix this problem.At the same time, My front-end colleague is also thinking about using spread.js to solve the problem